# How to resize the Headerarea in Avalonia UI TabControl?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I have an Avalonia UI app version 11.0.0-Preview8, and I want to shrink the height of the header area of the TabControl since it always seems to be slightly too big.
I haven't found a way to set the style in my axaml file. What's the recommended way of styling this area? I have tried to set the font size but that did not yield success.
Setting the MaxHeight or Height of the TabControl resizes everything, of course, and the content area of the TabControl isn't visible anymore.
[image: A screenshot of the TabControl with the Text Apples and Bananas. It visualizes the too big headarea.]

Here is my current code so far.

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" 
            Margin="0" Padding="0" 
            Background="{Binding ClickedColor}">

    <TabItem VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
             Margin="0" Padding="10 0">
        <TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Padding="0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">Apples</TextBlock>
        </TabItem.Header>
       
        <RandomControl />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
             Margin="0" Padding="10 0">
        <TabItem.Header>
          Bananas
        </TabItem.Header>  
        
        <RandomControl />
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to change the height of the TabItem header bar in the [Citrus.Avalonia Theme](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Citrus.Avalonia/blob/main/src/Citrus.Avalonia/Theme/TabControlStyles.xaml).

The style selector I needed was "TabControl WrapPanel". Setting the MaxHeight there results in a smaller TabItem header. I also added some other styles to make the font look better with the smaller header.

```
<Style Selector="TabControl WrapPanel">
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,0"/>
</Style>

<Style Selector="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>

<Style Selector="TabItem > TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

This is the smaller header with a backgroundcolor.

[image]